# endAllStagingAnimators on (RippleDrawable) with handle on RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have this Error when start activity , I'm using Recycle view :

Activity main XML :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:cacheColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
android:clipToPadding="false"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:paddingBottom="20dp"
android:paddingTop="20dp"
android:background="#fff"
android:id="@+id/maincat" />
```

Activity Main Java :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public String URL = "http://xx.com/xx/Services.asmx/xx";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.maincat);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    final MyRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(createMockList(), R.layout.activity_main_row));
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener<ViewModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, ViewModel viewModel) {
        //    adapter.goToSub(viewModel);
        }
    });
}

private List<ViewModel> createMockList() {

    final List<ViewModel> items = new ArrayList<>();
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new
            Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {

                        JSONArray obj = response.getJSONArray("Maincat");
                        for (int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = obj.getJSONObject(i);
                            String Maincatname = jsonObject.getString("Maincatname");
                            String MaincatImage = jsonObject.getString("MaincatImage");
                            int ID = jsonObject.getInt("ID");
                            items.add(new ViewModel(ID,Maincatname,MaincatImage));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("e", e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    queue.add(request);
    return items;
}
```

and the Recycler Adapter :

```
public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {


private  Context context;
private List<ViewModel> items;
private OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener<ViewModel> itemClickListener;
private int itemLayout;
private PaletteManager paletteManager = new PaletteManager();

public MyRecyclerAdapter(List<ViewModel> items, int itemLayout) {
    this.items = items;
    this.itemLayout = itemLayout;

}

@Override public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(itemLayout, parent, false);
    v.setOnClickListener(this);
    return new ViewHolder(v);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final ViewModel item = items.get(position);
    holder.itemView.setTag(item);
    holder.text.setText(item.getText());
    Picasso.with(holder.image.getContext()).load(item.getImage()).into(holder.image, new Callback() {
        @Override public void onSuccess() {
            holder.updatePalette(paletteManager);
        }

        @Override public void onError() {
        }
    });
}

@Override public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override public void onClick(View view) {
    if (itemClickListener != null) {
        ViewModel model = (ViewModel) view.getTag();
        itemClickListener.onItemClick(view, model);
        Sub_Cat sub_cat = new Sub_Cat();
        sub_cat.Sub_Category_ID = model.getId();
        final Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(context, Sub_Cat.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}


public void add(ViewModel item, int position) {
    items.add(position, item);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void goToSub(ViewModel item) {
    int position = items.indexOf(item);
}


public void setOnItemClickListener(OnRecyclerViewItemClickListener<ViewModel> listener) {
    this.itemClickListener = listener;
}



public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView image;
    public TextView text;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        context = itemView.getContext();
        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_maincat);
        text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_text_title);
    }

    public void updatePalette(PaletteManager paletteManager) {
        String key = ((ViewModel)itemView.getTag()).getImage();
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        paletteManager.getPalette(key, bitmap, new PaletteManager.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onPaletteReady(Palette palette) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

and the logcat erroe is :

> 10-17 07:57:14.080 28715-28715/com.momentstel.springpalestine
>   W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from
>   android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global,
>   returning read-only value. D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on
>   0x7f69171c00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7f7d62ca00 10-17
>   07:57:22.188 28715-28857/com.momentstel.springpalestine
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x7f69296400
>   (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7f7d62cf80 10-17 07:57:23.759
>   28715-28857/com.momentstel.springpalestine D/OpenGLRenderer:
>   endAllStagingAnimators on 0x7f693ffc00 (RippleDrawable) with handle
>   0x7f6653f3c0 10-17 07:57:24.756
>   28715-28857/com.momentstel.springpalestine D/OpenGLRenderer:
>   endAllStagingAnimators on 0x7f693df400 (RippleDrawable) with handle
>   0x7f6653f680

Please Help Me

Comment: you can refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/46939788/8203578